# Drag & drop or resize events inside React Big calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fullcalendar, react-redux, react-big-calendar

Can someone please explain how to resize the event ..i m fine with **DragAndDropCalendar** Component currently, but for my application i need able to resize the event as well
(please explain with code, i m just a newbie for React)

please check below for my current code which works fine and let me know if any modifcation to be done for resize event.

```
const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(BigCalendar);
```

and

```
<DragAndDropCalendar
             min={am8}
             max={pm8}
             selectable
             events={this.state.events}
             onEventDrop={this.moveEvent}
             defaultView="day"
               views={["month", "week", "day"]}
             onNavigate={(date, views) => {

             }}
             onView={view => {


             }}
              onSelectSlot={slot => this.createAppointment(slot)}
             onSelectEvent={event => this.modifyAppointment(event)}
           />
```

BTW i have found **DraggableEventWrapper** component  but not sure how to use..
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

line 38 in demo/dnd.js is currently:

`resizeEvent = (resizeType, { event, start, end }) => {`

and should be:

`resizeEvent(resizeType, { event, start, end }) {`

and then after line 19 in demo/dnd.js, the following should be added:

`this.resizeEvent = this.resizeEvent.bind(this)`

or refer this page
https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues/804